# Are Redis SINTER statements comparable to SQL WHERE statements?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, redis, mariadb

I'm trying to improve my understanding of Redis, as I have a project that needs to crunch a lot of numbers in a rapid fashion, however, I'm running into an issue and it's either my understanding is wrong or somehow my code isn't working as expected.

I have data in a MariaDB table, and I'm using `ioredis` to `hmset` the data for each line into the Redis database, then performing an `sadd` to create indices for each point that I need to pivot off of.

However, my result sets are not matching. For example, in the MariaDB I get a result set of of rougly 55k records off of two fields:

```
 SELECT COUNT(`Email`) FROM myTable 
 WHERE `Qual Field A`='Yes' AND `Qual Field B`='Something else'
```

using those same fields in Redis I'm getting results around 2k:

```
 SINTER qualFieldA:'Yes' qualFieldB:'Something else'
```

I was under the impression, based on what I'd read on SO and elsewhere, that doing a `SINTER key1:value key2:value` would be roughly the equivalent of `SELECT {fields} FROM {table} WHERE field1=value AND field2=value`.

Is that the case and perhaps my importing or sadd calls are off, or do I not properly understand how SINTER works?

Comment: If your Sets are populated correctly, the flow is correct. Perhaps share your import code?

Comment: Here's an example of my code for bringing in the records and `sadd`ing them. I'm thinking my keying in sadd() is off.

 https://jsbin.com/sefevihohe/1/edit?js,output

Comment: Your code looks sane. Note that the SINTER you've provided shouldn't include ticks (') in the key names unless they are actually a part of the data in data record object (which I tend to believe they're not)

Comment: Which number is "correct"?

Comment: @ItamarHaber Not sure what you mean by ticks in the key name. Are you referring to this line : `.then( () => redis.sadd( 'valueA:' + data[ 'Value A' ], data.Email ) )` ?

@RickJames ~55k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle you are right, however, besides errors in the import process, the main suspect IMO is this: MariaDB does index collation and normalizes values in certain ways for selection, while in redis what you see is what you get.

So for example, the values "Yes", "yes", "Yés" and "YES" in MariaDB will all be selected if you query for "Yes", in redis only the value for "Yes" will be.

And it's not just lowercase - if you deal with unicode you're entering a world of pain trying to implement normalization and collation by yourself.

Comment: I'm aware of the "yes" v "Yes" v "YES" matter. The weird thing is, it's more accurate when I put a `LIMIT` on the SQL query.

Comment: It was predominately an encoding issue, so I'm marking this as the correct answer. The reason I had more "accurate" results using `LIMIT` was because that subsection happened to match what I was searching against. Thank you.